# Python Facebook SDK: Getting information about a user's friends

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extend the example AppEngine application with Facebook login found [here](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py). I was able to get it to work as-is (with my own access token stuff added from a separate file), and it displays this nice little page (brought to you by this [example.html](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.html)) when a user logs in:

[image: main.html]

Now, I want to access information about the user's friends; e.g., the movies they have liked. To start, I added the a plethora of permissions to my underlying app on the Facebook developer's dashboard (e.g., friends_likes) and then saved changes. Then I decided to try displaying a single friend's name, along with his or her favorite movies. At the moment, I just explicitly store these things with the user and have thus modified the example.py file as follows (new lines end with "###################"):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2010 Facebook
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
# not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
# a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
# WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
# License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

"""
A barebones AppEngine application that uses Facebook for login.

1.  Make sure you add a copy of facebook.py (from python-sdk/src/)
    into this directory so it can be imported.
2.  Don't forget to tick Login With Facebook on your facebook app's
    dashboard and place the app's url wherever it is hosted
3.  Place a random, unguessable string as a session secret below in
    config dict.
4.  Fill app id and app secret.
5.  Change the application name in app.yaml.

"""

import facebook
import auth
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2
import urllib2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from webapp2_extras import sessions

config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = dict(secret_key=auth.SESSION_SECRET)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    friend_name = db.StringProperty(required=True) ######################
    friend_movies = db.StringProperty(required=True) ####################

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """Provides access to the active Facebook user in self.current_user

    The property is lazy-loaded on first access, using the cookie saved
    by the Facebook JavaScript SDK to determine the user ID of the active
    user. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for
    more information.
    """
    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if self.session.get("user"):
            # User is logged in
            return self.session.get("user")
        else:
            # Either used just logged in or just saw the first page
            # We'll see here
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies,
                                                   auth.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                                                   auth.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
            if cookie:
                # Okay so user logged in.
                # Now, check to see if existing user
                user = User.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])
                if not user:
                    # Not an existing user so get user info
                    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(cookie["access_token"])
                    profile = graph.get_object("me")
                    friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields="name")############
                    fname = friends["data"][0]["name"] ################
                    fid = friends["data"][0]["id"] ################
                    fmov = graph.get_connections(fid, "movies", fields="name")##############
                    user = User(
                        key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                        id=str(profile["id"]),
                        name=profile["name"],
                        friend_name=str(fname),##############
                        friend_movies=str(fmov),##############
                        profile_url=profile["link"],
                        access_token=cookie["access_token"]
                    )
                    user.put()
                elif user.access_token != cookie["access_token"]:
                    user.access_token = cookie["access_token"]
                    user.put()
                # User is now logged in
                self.session["user"] = dict(
                    name=user.name,
                    friend_name = user.friend_name, #################
                    friend_movies=user.friend_movies, ###############
                    profile_url=user.profile_url,
                    id=user.id,
                    access_token=user.access_token
                )
                return self.session.get("user")
        return None

    def dispatch(self):
        """
        This snippet of code is taken from the webapp2 framework documentation.
        See more at
        http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

        """
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        try:
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        """
        This snippet of code is taken from the webapp2 framework documentation.
        See more at
        http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

        """
        return self.session_store.get_session()


class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('main.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(dict(
            facebook_app_id=auth.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            current_user=self.current_user
        )))

    def post(self):
        url = self.request.get('url')
        file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(self.current_user['access_token'])
        response = graph.put_photo(file, "Test Image")
        photo_url = ("http://www.facebook.com/"
                     "photo.php?fbid={0}".format(response['id']))
        self.redirect(str(photo_url))


class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.current_user is not None:
            self.session['user'] = None

        self.redirect('/')

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__))
)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', HomeHandler), ('/logout', LogoutHandler)],
    debug=True,
    config=config
)
```

I added a couple of lines to the example.html file to convey the new information:

```
...

{% if current_user %}
    <p><a href="{{ current_user.profile_url }}">
        <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{ current_user.id }}/picture?type=square"/>
    </a></p>
    <p>Hello, {{ current_user.name|escape }}</p>
    <p>You have a friend named {{ current_user.friend_name|escape }}</p>  #################
    <p>Movies your friend likes, probably in some weird format: #################
        {{ current_user.friend_movies }}</p> ##############
{% endif %}

...
```

For my example Facebook account, which has one friend named "Sey Ian", the output is now:

[image]

I have two main questions:

1. Sey Ian DOES have some liked movies, so why aren't they displaying? Do I need to do something else permission-related within my code? Or am I accessing them with the wrong syntax (e.g., I need something like `friend_movies=str(fmov["data"][0]["name"])`...for the first movie in this case, kind of like how I access the name of the first friend)?
2. At some point, I will want to extract even more information about a user and his or her friends. With that in mind, are there any nice, THOROUGH examples of Python Facebook SDK graph calls? Figuring out how to do just what I have now has taken the good part of FOREVER.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Firebase authentication [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#firebase_authentication). Firebase Authentication provides multiple user authentication options including with Google, Facebook, and Twitter.